Miranda 530TZ Sync to pc cables
I have a Miranda 530TZ Flash unit, (used came without any other bits), that works OK, but I need a "sync to PC" cable. Are all sync cable jacks the same size? Many internet searches haven't produced definitive answer. the 'pc' end is standard but the flash unit size is debatable! Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

It is 3.5mm mono to PC........

Many Thanks as luck would have it, it's the only one i haven't got!
